# jQuery php to delete rows dynamically in table from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am have a page where i have the table row id defined by 'lesson_id' and i have a delete function for jquery that deletes that row without having to change page.
It is almost all working but when it posts the information to delete_row.php it is not deleting the record.
but delete_row.php is working because i've manually done delete_row.php?id=4 and it deleted that record succesfully.
Any pointers and explanations would be great as i'm still learning.

lessons.php

```
<table id="lessons" class="table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lesson ID</th>
            <th>Lesson Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr id="'. $row['lesson_id'].'">';    
        echo '<td>'. $row['lesson_id'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['name'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td><a class="delete">Delete</a></td>';   
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
<div id="error"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#lessons td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            //$('#error').html(data);
            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "delete_row.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

delete_row.php

```
<?php
include ('../../../config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (!$con){
    die('could not connect: '. mysqli_error($con));
}
$error = "";
$success = "";

if($_GET['id'])
{
$id = $_GET['id'];

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM module_lessons WHERE lesson_id='$id'");
}
?>
```

as its obvious ... this has no sql injection protection on it.

Comment: you never bothered embedding teh ID of the record in your delete link, so when the link is clicked, `$_GET['id']` is undefined. And **DON'T DO THIS** you are both vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and the [Spider of Doom](http://www.thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom). Enjoy having your server totally pwn3d.

Comment: You are mixing up GET and POST. You should only use POST; you don't want a clever browser (plugin...) or a search engine to prefetch all your delete links...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Apart from the problems mentioned already, you are using some sort of authentication in your real `delete_row.php` script, right?

Comment: this is a school project i'm learning and i know how to prevent sql injections and validations i've done it in my other forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$_GET['id'];` to `$_POST['id'];`

Here, you're doing a `POST` request:

```
type: "POST",
url: "delete_row.php",
```

... but in your PHP script you're checking for `GET`.

Also, as [marc b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) noted, you're currently vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: You can use prepared statements in mysqli as well.

Comment: @jeroen Wasn't aware of that. I've used PDO exclusively for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Me too. When I have the choice at least :-)

Comment: @BugHunterUK thanks for that that's the answer i been looking for didn't realise my muck up ... and yer i know that it is vulnerable i was trying to solve my problem first before i do that.